# Why is egrep ignoring the negative whitespace?

Tags: grep, regular-expression

Why doesn't `grep -E` work as I expect for negative whitespace? i.e. `[^\s]+`

I wrote a regex to parse my `.ssh/config`

`grep -Ei '^host\s+[^*\s]+\s*$' ~/.ssh/config`

```
# cat ~/.ssh/config
Host opengrok-01-Eight
    Hostname opengrok-01.company.com

Host opengrok-02-SIX
    Hostname opengrok-02.company.com

Host opengrok-03-forMe
    Hostname opengrok-03.company.com

Host opengrok-04-ForSam
    Hostname opengrok-04.company.com

Host opengrok-05-Okay
    Hostname opengrok-05.company.com

Host opengrok-05-Okay opengrok-03-forMe
    IdentityFile /path/to/file

Host opengrok-*
    User root
```

What I got was

```
Host opengrok-01-Eight
Host opengrok-03-forMe
Host opengrok-05-Okay
Host opengrok-05-Okay opengrok-03-forMe
```

Where are SIX and Sam!

It took me some time to realise that `[^\s*]+` i.e. Match anything that isn't white space or `*`, 1 or more times was actually match anything that isn't `\`, `s` or `*`, 1 or more times!

The fix is surprisingly easy because that regex works on rex101.com (which uses perl) i.e. switch `-E` for `-P`

```
# grep -Pi '^host\s+[^*\s]+\s*$' ~/.ssh/config
Host opengrok-01-Eight
Host opengrok-02-SIX
Host opengrok-03-forMe
Host opengrok-04-ForSam
Host opengrok-05-Okay
```

What scares me is I have been using `grep -E` for years in lots of scripts and not spotted that before. Maybe I've just got lucky but more likely my test cases have missed that edge case!

Questions:

1. Other than changing to use `grep -P` for all my extended regex how should I be writing my `grep -E` for this case?
2. Are there any other nasty gotchas that I have been missing with `-E` or that will bite me if I use `-P`?

---

```
grep (GNU grep) 3.1
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Mike Haertel and others, see <http://git.sv.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/AUTHORS>.
```

Running on Windows 10, WSL running Ubuntu 18.04 (bash) ... but I got the same from a proper Linux install

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The complement of `\s` is `\S`, not `[^\s]` which (with the help of `-i`) excluded 'SIX' and 'Sam' from the result because they contain a literal `s`.

---

How to `grep -i` for lines starting with "host", followed by one or more whitespaces and a sequence of one or more characters until the end of the line, where no literal `*` or whitespace can exist:

```bsh
grep -Ei '^host[[:space:]]+[^*[:space:]]+$' file
```

```
Host opengrok-01-Eight
Host opengrok-02-SIX
Host opengrok-03-forMe
Host opengrok-04-ForSam
Host opengrok-05-Okay
```

Comment: I had tried using `[[:space:]]` but I didn't understand the syntax when it was already inside `[^`. I was trying `[^[[:space:]]*]+`. Seems obvious now I've been shown

Answer (score 6):

Interpreting `\s` as whitespace is an extension of GNU Grep. It is not defined in [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html). [BSD Grep](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=grep&sektion=&n=1),
for example, does not identify `\s` as whitespace. Perl regexes are also an extension to POSIX, but both BSD
and GNU provide it. For a totally portable expression, you should use `[[:space:]]` instead.

[The GNU Grep manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions) states somewhat loosely that
"most meta-characters lose their special meaning inside bracket expressions." You have found that `\s` is one of them, and it is in fact specified by [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05) (again) that the special characters `.`, `*`, `[` and `\` should lose their special meaning within a bracket expression. But you can still portably use `[:space:]`.

So, answering your two questions,

> How should I be writing my `grep -E` for this case?

```
grep -Ei '^host[[:space:]]+[^*[:space:]]+[[:space:]]*$'
```

> Are there any other nasty gotchas that I have been missing with `-E` or that will bite me if I use `-P`?

A common mistake is to try the Perl non-greedy `.*?` with no `-P` flag.

```
$ echo 'AB 14 34' | grep -Eo '^.*?4'
AB 14 34
$ echo 'AB 14 34' | grep -Po '^.*?4'
AB 14
$ echo 'AB 14 34' | grep -o  '^.*?4'
{nothing}
```

The final word: [BRE and ERE](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Basic-vs-Extended.html) and PRE are all different. Know your regexes!

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I already gave the accepted to thanasisp as they got in first. Yours is a nice answer but is not quite enough of an improvement for me to switch.

Comment: @Martin No problem at all, both answers are quite similar and complement each other in some regards.

Comment: The main point is that while POSIX leaves the behaviour unspecified if you do `grep '\s'`, it requires `grep '[\s]'` to match on either ``\`` or `s` (which IMO is a poor decision as in practice using ``\`` non-doubled inside bracket expressions to match a ``\`` is not portable, so they might as well have left `[\s]` unspecified as well, allowing implementations to treat it specially, and require applications to do `[\\]` if they want to match on a ``\``)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thank you for pointing that, I have added the passage in POSIX that requires `[\s]` to match backslash or `s`.

Comment: Note that the ast-open implementation of `grep` supports `.*?` with `-E`. Again, POSIX leaves the behaviour for `x*?` unspecified so implementations are free to interpret it as they want such as implementing that perl extension.